# Can't read or write from gpio

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I am running `Linux pi 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) aarch64 GNU/Linux` on a raspberry pi 4 and trying to access the gpio pins.
I ran the following commands:

1. `sudo -i`
2. `echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export`

I got the following error:
`echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Does it work if you book RaspiOS 32 on your RPi?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to read gpio pins with golang by using [this](https://github.com/warthog618/gpiod) library.

Comment: This doesn't answer your own question. You asked for a solution using the shell, not one with an arbitrary language.